Getting Unauthorized Error in some JMeter Samplers after recording script
I am new to JMeter. I have been working as a ServiceNow Tester and have been instructed to learn JMeter for performing performance testing on SerivceNow applications. I have been practicing it on my PDI. I have created a new catalog item that triggers an approval request post Submission and on Approval triggers a catalog task. On Jmeter, I have recorded the test scripts using its record controller. I covered the steps where an end user logs in to the SP portal, navigates to the catalog item, inserts the details and submits the form. I removed the unnecessary samplers (any domain apart from the Google or SNOW PDU domain). Then I ran the recorded scripts using a View Results in Tree listener. I observed that some of the samplers failed. I also see error of 'unauthorized' and also 'no cache' in the respsonse headers. PFA SS. Please tell me how to overcome these bottlenecks. I am really clueless.
I also see the error of 'unauthorized' and also 'no cache' in the response headers. In order to troubleshoot,

I had added a Cookie Manager to my Test Plan,

I added an Authorization Manager put Base URL: http://localhost, Username, password, Mechanism=Basic

Added Beanshell Preprocessor with the script:
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; String username = vars.get("USERNAME"); String password = vars.get("PASSWORD"); String combineduserpass = username + ":" + password; byte\[\] encodedUsernamePassword = Base64.encodeBase64(combineduserpass.getBytes()); vars.put("base64HeaderValue",new String(encodedUsernamePassword));


Added Header Manager with the following headers:
Authorization    Basic ${base64HeaderValue}
Content-Type application/json


Still I am getting Unauthorized error.

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded script without prior correlation of the dynamic parameters.
Modern web applications including service now rely on dynamic values for security reasons or client-side state tracking. You can record the same scenario one more time and compare resulting JMeter scripts - all request parameters which will differ are a subject to correlation, you will need to:

Use suitable JMeter Post-Processors for extracting them from the previous responses
Replace recorded hard-coded values with the variables from the Post-Processors

Also be aware that there is JMeter Correlation Recorder plugin which can attempt to detect and handle dynamic parameters automatically or let you define custom correlation rules.

Hi, i retried using the bzm - auto corelation plugin, but still see errors in some of my samplers.. the error code is 400 Bad request. I see There is a Debus Post Processor that comes along with the remplate. I have enabled that as well. Any idea, what shall be the troubleshooting steps?
